# Robot Framework: Using python function (return value) as input parameter to Keyword input argument

Tags: python, robotframework, function-call

Is it possible to use python function return value implicit as keyword argument? I am aware that I can store the return value temporarily in a variable and use that variable as input argument in 2 lines.

Given the example python function in data.py:

```
def identifier(id):
    data = {'a' : 'jerry', 'b' : 'kramer', 'c' : 'elaine'}
    return data[id]
```

I want to call the function 'identifier' and use the returned value implicit in a keyword call:

```
*** Settings ***
Library             data.py

*** Test Cases ***
Implicit Call
    Log To Console   identifier  id=a
```

The above will not work. I would like the returned value from 'identifier' ('jerry') to be used as input to 'Log To Console' so the robot file writes 'jerry' to the console. The keyword 'Log To Console' is only used as an example. I need to do it for a number of other keywords. I would like to avoid using a temporary variable.

Comment: Robot Framework does not support running keywords like that. You must define a variable and use it in separate lines.

Answer (score 0):

The integration between Robot Framework and Python is very efficient and comfortable. I give you a way to get what I think you are looking for.

Notice how I write the import. It's just good practice.

```
Library   data.py   WITH NAME    UTILS

*** Test Cases ***
Implicit Call
  ${Result}= UTILS.identifier a
  Log To Console  The identifier I want is ${Result}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is not what I am looking for. The output from the identifier function is stored in a temporary variable ${Result} which is what I want to avoid. I want to do the call (and output) in one line. I did find a suitable solution to it my self and added an answer here but for some reason it has been deleted by moderators.